# Unable to send _$GET['username'] into the Database?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

For some strange reason I cannot insert a username into the database, but when I change the value into any integer it works once I click like, it works.

```
$postid = $_POST['postid'];
$userid = $_GET['username'];
$result = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM user_images WHERE id=$postid");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$n = $row['likes'];
mysqli_query($dbh,"INSERT INTO likes(username, postid) VALUES($userid, $postid)");
mysqli_query($dbh,"UPDATE user_images SET likes=$n+1 WHERE id=$postid");
echo $n+1;
exit();
```

Comment: You are open to SQL injections, which also is the reason why the strings fail to insert (although you could correct that another way). You also don't need `$n` just use the column value in the `update`.

Comment: First breakdown the code to better debugging, Check what is the result of that query in PHPMYADMIN or adminer and do var_dump() all variables like row and $n

Comment: You're fetching the parameters that you want to insert from `$_GET` and from `$_POST` - it should be the same for both depending on how you do the actual request (otherwise one of them will be empty). Or use the `$_REQUEST` collection to retrieve them.

Comment: mysqli_query($dbh,"INSERT INTO likes(username, postid) VALUES('$userid', '$postid')");

Comment: Thank you so much!